# Difference between two elements of different lists. Performance;

Tags: list, performance

Given two unsorted lists with whole numbers. I would like to write a function which takes both lists as arguments and returns the biggest and smallest difference between two numbers of these lists.

For Example.
arr1 = [-1, 34, 50, 3, 10]
arr2 = [37, 108, 78]

the biggest Difference would be 108 - (-1) = 109
the smallest Difference would be 37 - 34 = 3

My function so far.

```
def max_and_min(seq1, seq2): 
sortseq1 = sorted(seq1)
sortseq2 = sorted(seq2)

maxdiffer = max(abs(sortseq1[-1] - sortseq2[0]), abs(sortseq2[-1] - sortseq1[0]))
tmpmindiff1 = 10000000


if sortseq1[0] > sortseq2[-1]:
    tmpmindiff1 = abs(sortseq1[0] - sortseq2[-1])
    return (maxdiffer, tmpmindiff1)
elif sortseq2[0] > sortseq1[-1]:
    tmpmindiff1 = abs(sortseq2[0] - sortseq1[-1])
    return (maxdiffer, tmpmindiff1)

for i in sortseq1:
    tmpdiff2 = 1000000
    for j in sortseq2:
        diff = abs(i - j)                        
        if diff == 0:
            return (maxdiffer, 0)
        elif diff <= tmpdiff2:
            tmpdiff2 = diff
            if j == sortseq2[-1]:
                if tmpdiff2 <= tmpmindiff1:
                    tmpmindiff1 = tmpdiff2
        elif diff > tmpdiff2:
            if tmpdiff2 <= tmpmindiff1:
                tmpmindiff1 = tmpdiff2                
            break
                
return (maxdiffer, tmpmindiff1)
```

The Code does its basic job and returns correct results but it is too slow. So would really appreciate any suggestions to make it faster. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For biggest difference it is enough to find maximum element in second list and minimum of first list and subtract its values.

For smallest difference you have to subtract minimum of second list and maximum of first list.

```
def max_and_min(seq1, seq2):
    return (max(seq2) - min(seq1), min(seq2) - max(seq1))
```

P.S
If you meant maximum and minimum differences by its absolute value it is another problem.

Comment: In either case your code will give the wrong result. You can see that in the example i stated. But the question is for the absolute value.

Comment: In the example which you stated answer is 37-50=-13 because -13 is smaller than 3.